# Styling JS-Generated Code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using a "find and replace" type javascript function, and replacing all the backticks in the HTML with `<code>` tags, and all the pound signs with `</code>` tags. For some reason my styles are not working unless I code them in on the JS file with the `.css()` method.

Ideally, the combo should output the code between backticks and pound signs as blocked `<code>` content, (the `<code>` tags are generated from JavaScript) with a soft gray background. However, for some reason the styles just don't show up.

If any one can help, I'd greatly appreciate it.

This is my html file `test.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Script Test</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/code/style.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<p>This is some code:
    `var p = 10; #  
    `var a = 5; #   
    `var x; #   
    `x = a * p; #    
    `console.log(x); #
    All I want is for this to work!
</p>
<script src="codeStyle.js"></script>
</body>
```

My CSS file (compiled from SASS) `style.css`:

```
body {
  color: #121212;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  letter-spacing: .25px; }

  body div.container {
    padding: 10px; }

    body div.container code.styled {
      font-family: arial, serif;
      background-color: #f9f9f9; /* soft gray bg color */
      display: block; /* block display style */
      margin: 2px 0 2px 2.5%;
      padding: 3px;
      width: auto;
      background-color: #fafafa;
      border: 1px solid #f5f5f5; }

 /*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

And my js file `codeStyle.js`:

```
$('p').each(function() {
var text = $(this).html(); // Grab HTML from each <p>
text = text.replace(/`/gi,"<code class='styled'>"); // Replaces every ` with <code>
text = text.replace(/#/gi,"</code>"); // Replaces every # with </code>
$(this).html(text); // Set <p> html as replaced code
});
```

Comment: Your code elements are not inside a div with class `container` so your css selector is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To put Partick's answer up: Your CSS is trying to target an element that doesn't exist.

The problem is in this bit of CSS:

```
 body div.container code.styled { }
```

There is no content that matches this selector, as there is no `<div class="container">`

To get around this, you can either remove the offending selector from the CSS:

```
body code.styled {}
```

or add the requied selector to your HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <p>Some text <code class="styled">some code</code>.</p>
</div>
```

Here's a **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/timmah/2no7juor/)** of it working.